# SVG transform origin and box with small viewBox and floated numbers

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, css-transforms

## Definition

In Firefox in order to have real `transform-origin: center` we have to add `transform-box: fill-box`. It works very well in casual situations, but there are some problems.

When we have small svg's viewBox (eg. `<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">`) and we have to use floated numbers in order to provide exact center position in svg space there is some strange behaviour — `fill-box` is ignored.

## Example

https://jsfiddle.net/6jckL4ne/

```css
@keyframes animRotate {
 from {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
svg {
 background-color: pink;
}
.spin {
 animation: animRotate 3s infinite;
 transform-origin: center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 fill: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <rect class="spin" height=".5" width=".5" x="0.25" y="0.25"/>
 <line x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y1="0" y2="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"></line>
 <line x1="0" x2="1" y1="0.5" y2="0.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"></line>
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect class="spin" height="50" width="50" x="25" y="25"/>
 <line x1="50" x2="50" y1="0" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
 <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="50" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
</svg>
</body>
```

## Expected result

Both rectangles (left and right) should be rotating in the center of each svg (the point of the intersection of two black lines).

## How to resolve this problem or is it deep bug in Firefox browser?

Comment: Interesting catch, could well be a bug.

Comment: Another thing is the `stroke-width` in each SVG. Left svg has bolder (bigger) lines than right one. Like the width would be rounded instead of setting exact number (eg. `round(0.01)=0.05`).

Comment: let's wait for @RobertLongson, he will tell us if it's a bug or not ;)

Comment: Funny thing to try: Show as full page and use the browser zoom functions: at 200%, the left square moves to the bottom-right quadrant, and then gradually comes nearer to the center when you zoom further in. But it is worth noticing that the error is not in the `transform-origin`, the square rotates around its center as it should. It is the positioning of the rect that goes wrong when a transform is set (even true for `translate(0)`, `rotate(0)` or `scale(1)`, and independent of the setting of `tranform-origin` and `tranform-box`.

Comment: Looks like another example of [bug 1396642](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396642). Basically a viewBox bug, not a transform-origin/transform-box bug.