How do you add text on top of an svg path?


#us-map {
  display  : block;
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  }
path:hover {
  stroke          : #ffffff !important;
  stroke-width    : 2px;
  stroke-linejoin : round;
  fill            : #D3D3D3 !important;
  cursor          : pointer;
  }
text {
  dominant-baseline : central;
  text-anchor       : middle;
  fill              : black;
  font-size         : 55px;
  position          : absolute;
  z-index           : 2000;
  }
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="Map.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
  <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2"> </sodipodi:namedview>
  <g id="g5">
    <text font-size="42.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" y="300" x="0" cursor="pointer">HI</text>
    <path data-state="HI" fill="#4bb95a" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
    <path data-state="AK" fill="#4bb95a" d="M332.1,553.7l-0.3,85.4l1.6,1l3.1,0.2l1.5-1.1h2.6l0.2,2.9l7,6.8l0.5,2.6l3.4-1.9l0.6-0.2l0.3-3.1   l1.5-1.6l1.1-0.2l1.9-1.5l3.1,2.1l0.6,2.9l1.9,1.1l1.1,2.4l3.9,1.8l3.4,6l2.7,3.9l2.3,2.7l1.5,3.7l5,1.8l5.2,2.1l1,4.4l0.5,3.1   l-1,3.4l-1.8,2.3l-1.6-0.8l-1.5-3.1l-2.7-1.5l-1.8-1.1l-0.8,0.8l1.5,2.7l0.2,3.7l-1.1,0.5l-1.9-1.9l-2.1-1.3l0.5,1.6l1.3,1.8   l-0.8,0.8c0,0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1c-0.5-0.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3c0,0-0.3,1.3-1,1c-0.6-0.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9l-1.5-1.5v-5h-0.8   l-0.8,3.4l-1.1,0.5l-1-3.7l-0.6-3.7l-0.8-0.5l0.3,5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3l-3.6-6l-2.1-0.5l-0.6-3.7l-1.6-2.9l-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3   l-0.5-0.3l-2.6,0.6l-3.4-2.4l-2.6-2.9l-4.8-2.6l-4-2.6l1.3-3.2v-1.6l-1.8,1.6l-2.9,1.1l-3.7-1.1l-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-0.6,0.5l-6.5-3.9   l-2.1-0.3l-2.7-5.8l-3.6,0.3l-3.6,1.5l0.5,4.5l1.1-2.9l1,0.3l-1.5,4.4l3.2-2.7l0.6,1.6l-3.9,4.4l-1.3-0.3l-0.5-1.9l-1.3-0.8   l-1.3,1.1l-2.7-1.8l-3.1,2.1l-1.8,2.1l-3.4,2.1l-4.7-0.2l-0.5-2.1l3.7-0.6v-1.3l-2.3-0.6l1-2.4l2.3-3.9v-1.8l0.2-0.8l4.4-2.3l1,1.3   h2.7l-1.3-2.6l-3.7-0.3l-5,2.7l-2.4,3.4l-1.8,2.6l-1.1,2.3l-4.2,1.5l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.6l2.3,1l0.8,2.1l-2.7,3.2l-6.5,4.2l-7.8,4.2   l-2.1,1.1l-5.3,1.1l-5.3,2.3l1.8,1.3l-1.5,1.5l-0.5,1.1l-2.7-1l-3.2,0.2l-0.8,2.3h-1l0.3-2.4l-3.6,1.3l-2.9,1l-3.4-1.3l-2.9,1.9   h-3.2l-2.1,1.3l-1.6,0.8l-2.1-0.3l-2.6-1.1l-2.3,0.6l-1,1l-1.6-1.1v-1.9l3.1-1.3l6.3,0.6l4.4-1.6l2.1-2.1l2.9-0.6l1.8-0.8l2.7,0.2   l1.6,1.3l1-0.3l2.3-2.7l3.1-1l3.4-0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.5h0.8l1.3-3.7l4-1.5l1.9-3.7l2.3-4.5l1.6-1.5l0.3-2.6l-1.6,1.3l-3.4,0.6   l-0.6-2.4l-1.3-0.3l-1,1l-0.2,2.9l-1.5-0.2l-1.5-5.8l-1.3,1.3l-1.1-0.5l-0.3-1.9l-4,0.2l-2.1,1.1l-2.6-0.3l1.5-1.5l0.5-2.6   l-0.6-1.9l1.5-1l1.3-0.2l-0.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1l-0.8,1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3l-0.6-3.9l-2.1-3.6v-1l2.1-0.8l0.2-2.1l1.1-1.1l-0.8-0.5   l-1.3,0.5l-1.1-2.7l1-5l4.5-3.2l2.6-1.6l1.9-3.7l2.7-1.3l2.6,1.1l0.3,2.4l2.4-0.3l3.2-2.4l1.6,0.6l1,0.6h1.6l2.3-1.3l0.8-4.4   c0,0,0.3-2.9,1-3.4c0.6-0.5,1-1,1-1l-1.1-1.9l-2.6,0.8l-3.2,0.8l-1.9-0.5l-3.6-1.8l-5-0.2l-3.6-3.7l0.5-3.9l0.6-2.4l-2.1-1.8   l-1.9-3.7l0.5-0.8l6.8-0.5h2.1l1,1h0.6l-0.2-1.6l3.9-0.6l2.6,0.3l1.5,1.1l-1.5,2.1l-0.5,1.5l2.7,1.6l5,1.8l1.8-1l-2.3-4.4l-1-3.2   l1-0.8l-3.4-1.9l-0.5-1.1l0.5-1.6l-0.8-3.9l-2.9-4.7l-2.4-4.2l2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8,0.6l4.2-0.2l3.7-3.6l1.1-3.1l3.7-2.4l1.6,1l2.7-0.6   l3.7-2.1l1.1-0.2l1,0.8l4.5-0.2l2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6,2.4l1.9,2.1l-0.5,1.1l0.6,1.1l1.6-1.6l3.9,0.3l0.3,3.7l1.9,1.5l7.1,0.6l6.3,4.2   l1.5-1l5.2,2.6l2.1-0.6l1.9-0.8l4.8,1.9L332.1,553.7z M217,582.6l2.1,5.3l-0.2,1l-2.9-0.3l-1.8-4l-1.8-1.5H210l-0.2-2.6l1.8-2.4   l1.1,2.4l1.5,1.5L217,582.6z M214.4,616.1l3.7,0.8l3.7,1l0.8,1l-1.6,3.7l-3.1-0.2l-3.4-3.6L214.4,616.1z M193.7,602l1.1,2.6   l1.1,1.6l-1.1,0.8l-2.1-3.1V602H193.7z M180,675.1l3.4-2.3l3.4-1l2.6,0.3l0.5,1.6l1.9,0.5l1.9-1.9l-0.3-1.6l2.7-0.6l2.9,2.6   l-1.1,1.8l-4.4,1.1l-2.7-0.5l-3.7-1.1l-4.4,1.5l-1.6,0.3L180,675.1z M228.9,670.6l1.6,1.9l2.1-1.6l-1.5-1.3L228.9,670.6z    M231.8,673.6l1.1-2.3l2.1,0.3l-0.8,1.9H231.8z M255.4,671.7l1.5,1.8l1-1.1l-0.8-1.9L255.4,671.7z M264.2,659.2l1.1,5.8l2.9,0.8   l5-2.9l4.4-2.6l-1.6-2.4l0.5-2.4l-2.1,1.3l-2.9-0.8l1.6-1.1l1.9,0.8l3.9-1.8l0.5-1.5l-2.4-0.8l0.8-1.9l-2.7,1.9l-4.7,3.6l-4.8,2.9   L264.2,659.2z M306.5,639.4l2.4-1.5l-1-1.8l-1.8,1L306.5,639.4z"/>
  </g>
</svg>



Please assist me with the proper way to add labels on top of the SVG states. I have tried the following, but have not been able to display the text above the states (even after z-index:-1; is applied to the svg)
<text font-size="42.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" y="43" x="61" cursor="pointer">AK</text>


haven't you noticed that the SVG language is a vector language?, which implies that there can be no unity on the values, even in the CSS part...

@Mister Jojo: quite a few svg elements and attributes allow absolute or relative units - most importantly primitives like <rect> , <circle> etc. which e.g. permits to specify a width in inch and the height in cm. In CSS you often need add explicit units to attributes that would be unitless. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005738/svg-styles-with-absolute-units. The main problem here is  - we can't apply z-index to svg elements.

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="Map.svg"
      inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
  <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2"> </sodipodi:namedview>
  <g id="g5">
    <text font-size="42.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" y="300" x="0" cursor="pointer">HI</text>
    <path data-state="HI" fill="#4bb95a" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
    <path data-state="AK" fill="#4bb95a" d="M332.1,553.7l-0.3,85.4l1.6,1l3.1,0.2l1.5-1.1h2.6l0.2,2.9l7,6.8l0.5,2.6l3.4-1.9l0.6-0.2l0.3-3.1   l1.5-1.6l1.1-0.2l1.9-1.5l3.1,2.1l0.6,2.9l1.9,1.1l1.1,2.4l3.9,1.8l3.4,6l2.7,3.9l2.3,2.7l1.5,3.7l5,1.8l5.2,2.1l1,4.4l0.5,3.1   l-1,3.4l-1.8,2.3l-1.6-0.8l-1.5-3.1l-2.7-1.5l-1.8-1.1l-0.8,0.8l1.5,2.7l0.2,3.7l-1.1,0.5l-1.9-1.9l-2.1-1.3l0.5,1.6l1.3,1.8   l-0.8,0.8c0,0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1c-0.5-0.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3c0,0-0.3,1.3-1,1c-0.6-0.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9l-1.5-1.5v-5h-0.8   l-0.8,3.4l-1.1,0.5l-1-3.7l-0.6-3.7l-0.8-0.5l0.3,5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3l-3.6-6l-2.1-0.5l-0.6-3.7l-1.6-2.9l-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3   l-0.5-0.3l-2.6,0.6l-3.4-2.4l-2.6-2.9l-4.8-2.6l-4-2.6l1.3-3.2v-1.6l-1.8,1.6l-2.9,1.1l-3.7-1.1l-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-0.6,0.5l-6.5-3.9   l-2.1-0.3l-2.7-5.8l-3.6,0.3l-3.6,1.5l0.5,4.5l1.1-2.9l1,0.3l-1.5,4.4l3.2-2.7l0.6,1.6l-3.9,4.4l-1.3-0.3l-0.5-1.9l-1.3-0.8   l-1.3,1.1l-2.7-1.8l-3.1,2.1l-1.8,2.1l-3.4,2.1l-4.7-0.2l-0.5-2.1l3.7-0.6v-1.3l-2.3-0.6l1-2.4l2.3-3.9v-1.8l0.2-0.8l4.4-2.3l1,1.3   h2.7l-1.3-2.6l-3.7-0.3l-5,2.7l-2.4,3.4l-1.8,2.6l-1.1,2.3l-4.2,1.5l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.6l2.3,1l0.8,2.1l-2.7,3.2l-6.5,4.2l-7.8,4.2   l-2.1,1.1l-5.3,1.1l-5.3,2.3l1.8,1.3l-1.5,1.5l-0.5,1.1l-2.7-1l-3.2,0.2l-0.8,2.3h-1l0.3-2.4l-3.6,1.3l-2.9,1l-3.4-1.3l-2.9,1.9   h-3.2l-2.1,1.3l-1.6,0.8l-2.1-0.3l-2.6-1.1l-2.3,0.6l-1,1l-1.6-1.1v-1.9l3.1-1.3l6.3,0.6l4.4-1.6l2.1-2.1l2.9-0.6l1.8-0.8l2.7,0.2   l1.6,1.3l1-0.3l2.3-2.7l3.1-1l3.4-0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.5h0.8l1.3-3.7l4-1.5l1.9-3.7l2.3-4.5l1.6-1.5l0.3-2.6l-1.6,1.3l-3.4,0.6   l-0.6-2.4l-1.3-0.3l-1,1l-0.2,2.9l-1.5-0.2l-1.5-5.8l-1.3,1.3l-1.1-0.5l-0.3-1.9l-4,0.2l-2.1,1.1l-2.6-0.3l1.5-1.5l0.5-2.6   l-0.6-1.9l1.5-1l1.3-0.2l-0.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1l-0.8,1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3l-0.6-3.9l-2.1-3.6v-1l2.1-0.8l0.2-2.1l1.1-1.1l-0.8-0.5   l-1.3,0.5l-1.1-2.7l1-5l4.5-3.2l2.6-1.6l1.9-3.7l2.7-1.3l2.6,1.1l0.3,2.4l2.4-0.3l3.2-2.4l1.6,0.6l1,0.6h1.6l2.3-1.3l0.8-4.4   c0,0,0.3-2.9,1-3.4c0.6-0.5,1-1,1-1l-1.1-1.9l-2.6,0.8l-3.2,0.8l-1.9-0.5l-3.6-1.8l-5-0.2l-3.6-3.7l0.5-3.9l0.6-2.4l-2.1-1.8   l-1.9-3.7l0.5-0.8l6.8-0.5h2.1l1,1h0.6l-0.2-1.6l3.9-0.6l2.6,0.3l1.5,1.1l-1.5,2.1l-0.5,1.5l2.7,1.6l5,1.8l1.8-1l-2.3-4.4l-1-3.2   l1-0.8l-3.4-1.9l-0.5-1.1l0.5-1.6l-0.8-3.9l-2.9-4.7l-2.4-4.2l2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8,0.6l4.2-0.2l3.7-3.6l1.1-3.1l3.7-2.4l1.6,1l2.7-0.6   l3.7-2.1l1.1-0.2l1,0.8l4.5-0.2l2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6,2.4l1.9,2.1l-0.5,1.1l0.6,1.1l1.6-1.6l3.9,0.3l0.3,3.7l1.9,1.5l7.1,0.6l6.3,4.2   l1.5-1l5.2,2.6l2.1-0.6l1.9-0.8l4.8,1.9L332.1,553.7z M217,582.6l2.1,5.3l-0.2,1l-2.9-0.3l-1.8-4l-1.8-1.5H210l-0.2-2.6l1.8-2.4   l1.1,2.4l1.5,1.5L217,582.6z M214.4,616.1l3.7,0.8l3.7,1l0.8,1l-1.6,3.7l-3.1-0.2l-3.4-3.6L214.4,616.1z M193.7,602l1.1,2.6   l1.1,1.6l-1.1,0.8l-2.1-3.1V602H193.7z M180,675.1l3.4-2.3l3.4-1l2.6,0.3l0.5,1.6l1.9,0.5l1.9-1.9l-0.3-1.6l2.7-0.6l2.9,2.6   l-1.1,1.8l-4.4,1.1l-2.7-0.5l-3.7-1.1l-4.4,1.5l-1.6,0.3L180,675.1z M228.9,670.6l1.6,1.9l2.1-1.6l-1.5-1.3L228.9,670.6z    M231.8,673.6l1.1-2.3l2.1,0.3l-0.8,1.9H231.8z M255.4,671.7l1.5,1.8l1-1.1l-0.8-1.9L255.4,671.7z M264.2,659.2l1.1,5.8l2.9,0.8   l5-2.9l4.4-2.6l-1.6-2.4l0.5-2.4l-2.1,1.3l-2.9-0.8l1.6-1.1l1.9,0.8l3.9-1.8l0.5-1.5l-2.4-0.8l0.8-1.9l-2.7,1.9l-4.7,3.6l-4.8,2.9   L264.2,659.2z M306.5,639.4l2.4-1.5l-1-1.8l-1.8,1L306.5,639.4z"/>
  </g>

<g>
    <text data-state="HI" font-size="42.5" y="300" x="-100" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" cursor="pointer">HI</text>
    <text data-state="AK" font-size="42.5" y="300" x="-275" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" cursor="pointer">AK</text>
    </g>

</svg>

Adding the text below the paths, and wrapping in < g > has moved the text to above the SVG path.
